# How to get latest date (most recent date) in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two dates in one column.
I want get last date (large date or the most recent date)
so when I use `=MAX(A1:A10)` it returns a value (42343) like this or similar.
How to get the latest date by using the above formula?

Comment: try to format the cell (where this formula =max(A1:A10) resides) as date.  It works for me when I enter in this format 23-May-15.

Answer (score 1):

As @Prasanna points out, it's a formatting problem. Internally Excel represents date/time values as numbers, where the date is an integer representing the number of days since 1 Jan 1900, and the time is a fraction.

When you enter the `MAX` formula, it doesn't always determine the correct formatting to use. In Excel 2010, use the dropdown box in the **Number** section of the **Home** tab to select the **Date** format. Or select one of your original cells, and use the Format Painter to copy the formatting to the `MAX` cell.